# Compactness of bounded measures with respect to weak topology.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Consider the vector space of signed measures $\{m\}$ on $[0,1]$. Endow it with the weak topology generated by all functionals obtained as integral of a continuous function: $\int_{[0,1]} f dm, f \in C^0[0,1]$. Question: is the set of positive measures $m$ with $m([0,1]) \leq 1$ compact? Thanks for clarifying, Marco.

Comment: Yes, it is. Read about Helly's selectionTheorem.

Comment: Many thanks! Helly’s theorem proves sequentially compactness. Sequentially compactness implies compactness in metric spaces. The considered set can be made metric by Levy-Prokhorov distance. However, my difficulty is: is [topology induced by Levy-Prokhorov distance] = [weak topology generated by all functionals obtained as integral of a continuous functions]? I expect so because weak convergence is equivalent to convergence in Levy-Prokhorov metric. However, I cannot prove it myself, nor can I find it stated anywhere. Can you help? My apology if the question is deemed trivial. Best, Marco.